# not able to create directories recursively using os.makedirs()

Tags: python

this is a code snippet... not very effecient but very basic... but the issue it comes out without any errors and doesnt actually create /tmp/ctp/ in the desired dir.. is there something totally wrong with the code ?

```
import os
import sys

print ("Checking all required directories first...")

def checkDir():
    CurrentDir=os.getcwd()
    if (CurrentDir == '/home/aspx/psharma1'):
        print("Current dir is ok, Checking if CTP dir is created")
        if os.path.isdir('/tmp/ctp/'):
            print("CTP dir exists, please proceed")
        else:
            os.makedirs('/tmp/ctp/')
            os.chmod('/tmp/ctp/',0777)
    else:
        print('Current dir is not ok,Changing dir to psharma1 home')
        os.chdir('/home/aspx/psharma1')
        if os.path.isdir('/tmp/ctp/'):
            print("CTP dir exists, please proceed")
        else:
            os.makedirs('/tmp/ctp/')
            os.chmod('/tmp/ctp/',0777)

checkDir()
```

Comment: Well, there appears to be some rather odd duplication in the code, but "/tmp/ctp/" is an absolute path (starts with / which is the root directory). It's always going to make ctp in /tmp, nowhere else. Where did you expect it?

Another issue is that you've hardcoded a name in /tmp, which will collide if your program is run multiple times - in particular by different users.

Comment: The call to `chmod` is unnecessary as well; 777 is the default for `os.makedirs` (and can be overridden if needed--`os.makedirs(somedir, mode='755')`--to avoid any race conditions where the directory exists temporarily with the wrong permissions).

Comment: Duplication is because i;m doing makedirs twice .. i can correct that.. but to answer your ques im expecting the tmp/ctp in /home/aspx/psharma1... will that work if i just remove / ?

Comment: You might find [the pathlib module](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/pathlib.html) useful.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the errors mentioned in the comments, you really should avoid checking for the directory before you create it, as this introduces a race condition. Just try to create the directory, and catch the `FileExistsError` (assuming Python 3) that occurs if the directory already exists.

```
def check_dir():
    current_dir = os.getcwd()
    if current_dir != '/home/aspx/psharma1':
        print('Current dir is not ok, changing to psharma1 home', file=sys.stderr)
        os.chdir('/home/aspx/psharma1')

    try:
        os.makedirs('tmp/ctp')
    except FileExistsError:
        print('CTP dir exists, please proceed', file=sys.stderr)
```

For that matter, you don't even need to change the working directory; just pass the correct absolute path to the call to `makedirs`:

```
def check_dir():
    try:
        os.makedirs('/home/aspx/psharma1/tmp/ctp')
    except FileExistsError:
        print('CTP dir exists, please proceed', file=sys.stderr)
```

In Python 2.x, `makedirs` simply raises an `OSError`, and you need to check
the error number to distinguish between the expected file exists error and other more serious errors that should be re-raised instead of ignored.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import errno

try:
    os.makedirs('tmp/ctp')
except OSError as exc:
    if exc.errno != errno.EEXIST:
        raise
    print('CTP dir exists, please proceed', file=sys.stderr)
```

Comment: Chepner.. thanks but im using 2.6... is there something similar i can use ?

Comment: In 2.6, you just catch the `OSError` and check its `errno`; I'll update.

Comment: The function works the same in Python 2, but the exception happened to be an `OSError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: 'foo2/bar/'`

Comment: I'm not quite sure what triggers that error; I'm getting `OSError: [Errno 17] File exists: 'foo/bar'` for an existing directory.

Comment: Oh, right; error numbers are not standardized; updating again to use the `errno` module that I should have used in the first place.

Comment: @ chepner - if i use your first code (un-edited one) , it creates the dir , but when i run again it throws below error for an existing dir , and not what Yann mentioned.

Comment: Checking all required directories first...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CTP_Installation.py", line 12, in <module>
    checkDir()
  File "CTP_Installation.py", line 9, in checkDir
    except FileExistsError:
NameError: global name 'FileExistsError' is not defined

Comment: @pulkit Yes, `FileExistsError` is new in Python 3.3; for Python 2.6 (or any version of Python prior to 3.3), you need to use the code I posted at the bottom of the answer.

Comment: @chepner - worked perfectly , thanks a lot.. are there any good docs i can read for file i/o ops ?